# Checking if instance is null VS calling empty function (C#)

Tags: c#, game-engine

**Introduction**

So I was making a game, thinking how do I structure and update all my game objects. Do I (***case 1***) create a simple `GameObj` as a parent class and put some physics in `virtual Update` method, some default drawing in `virtual Draw`, etc, and make every other object (wall, enemy, player...) be the child, **OR** do I  (***case 2***) use components as described in [this article](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html). In short, the writer explains that we could make interfaces for user input, physics update and draw (lets stop at those 3) and describe our `GameObj` with preprogrammed instances of these interfaces.

Now, in both cases I will get a loop of `GameObj` class. 
In *case 1* it would probably look something like this

```
// in Update function of the level class
for(int i = 0; i < gameObjList.Count; i++)
{
    gameObjList[i].Update();
}
```

And in *case 2*, something like this

```
// in UpdatePhysics function of the level class
for(int i = 0; i < gameObjList.Count; i++)
{
    gameObjList[i].PhysicComponent.Update();
}
```

And so on (in *case 2*) for other interfaces such as `InputComponent.Update` and `DrawComponent.Draw` (or `CollisionComponent.Check(gameObj[x])`, I dunno).

*Reasons listed are ment to be inside a level class that takes care of all of our game objects*

**Reasons to consider `if ( x != null )`**
In both cases we (could) have a situation where we need to call `if ( x != null )`. In *case 1* we maybe don't want to delete and add to the `gameObjList` all the time, but recycle the instances, so we set them to `null` without doing something along the lines of `gameObjList.Remove(x)`. In *case 2* maybe we want to be able not to set some of the components, so we'd have to ask `if (gameObjList[i].someComponent != null)` to be able to call `gameObjList[i].someComponent.Update()`.

**Reasons to consider calling empty function**
Also in both cases, we could just call an empty function (e.g. `public void myFunction(){}`). Lets consider the self explanatory `Wall` class. It exists just to be there. Id doesn't update, but it does have a certain relation to other `GameObj`s. Also, some of it's children in *case 1*, like a lets say `MovingWall` or `Platform` would have some sort of update. As for *case 2*, we could always declare a default, empty class of `someComponent` whose `Update` function would be empty, and so an instance of this class would be set to our `GameObj` component if none is set in the constructor. Maybe something like this

```
public GameObj(IPhysicsComponent physicsComponent, ...){
    if(physicsComponent == null)
        physicsComponent = PhysicsComponent.Default;

    this.physicsComponent = physicsComponent;
}
```

**Research**
Now, I didn't find what would be the most efficient thing to do in a game engine we are building here. Here are some examples I just tested (*note* some of them are just for reference):
**1.** empty loop
**2.** empty function
**3.** `if(x != null) x.empyFunction();` x is always null 
**4.** `x?.emptyFunction();` x is always null 
**5.** `if(x != null) x.empyFunction();` x is not null
**6.** `x?.emptyFunction();` x is not null
**7.** `myClass.staticEmptyFunction();`

These 7 points are tested 100 000 times, 10 000 times. The code below is the code that I tested with. You can run in locally, change some of the static variables, and the result will appear in "result.txt" in the folder where you ran the program. Here is the code :

```
public enum TimeType
{
    emptyLoop = 1,
    loopEmptyFunction = 2,
    loopNullCheck = 3,
    loopNullCheckShort = 4,
    loopNullCheckInstanceNotNull = 5,
    loopNullCheckInstanceNotNullShort = 6,
    loopEmptyStaticFunction = 7
}

class myTime
{
    public double miliseconds { get; set; }
    public long ticks { get; set; }
    public TimeType type { get; set; }

    public myTime() { }
    public myTime(Stopwatch stopwatch, TimeType type)
    {
        miliseconds = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
        ticks = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
        this.type = type;
    }

}

class myClass
{
    public static void staticEmptyFunction() { }
    public void emptyFunction() { }
}

class Program
{
    static List<myTime> timesList = new List<myTime>();
    static int testTimesCount = 10000;
    static int oneTestDuration = 100000;


    static void RunTest()
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        Console.Write("TEST ");

        for (int j = 0; j < testTimesCount; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}, ", j + 1);
            myClass myInstance = null;


            // 1. EMPTY LOOP
            stopwatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < oneTestDuration; i++)
            {

            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            timesList.Add(new myTime(stopwatch, (TimeType)1));
            stopwatch.Reset();


            // 3. LOOP WITH NULL CHECKING (INSTANCE IS NULL)
            stopwatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < oneTestDuration; i++)
            {
                if (myInstance != null)
                    myInstance.emptyFunction();
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            timesList.Add(new myTime(stopwatch, (TimeType)3));
            stopwatch.Reset();


            // 4. LOOP WITH SHORT NULL CHECKING (INSTANCE IS NULL)
            stopwatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < oneTestDuration; i++)
            {
                myInstance?.emptyFunction();
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            timesList.Add(new myTime(stopwatch, (TimeType)4));
            stopwatch.Reset();


            myInstance = new myClass();

            // 2. LOOP WITH EMPTY FUNCTION
            stopwatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < oneTestDuration; i++)
            {
                myInstance.emptyFunction();
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            timesList.Add(new myTime(stopwatch, (TimeType)2));
            stopwatch.Reset();


            // 5. LOOP WITH NULL CHECKING (INSTANCE IS NOT NULL)
            stopwatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < oneTestDuration; i++)
            {
                if (myInstance != null)
                    myInstance.emptyFunction();
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            timesList.Add(new myTime(stopwatch, (TimeType)5));
            stopwatch.Reset();


            // 6. LOOP WITH SHORT NULL CHECKING (INSTANCE IS NOT NULL)
            stopwatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < oneTestDuration; i++)
            {
                myInstance?.emptyFunction();
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            timesList.Add(new myTime(stopwatch, (TimeType)6));
            stopwatch.Reset();


            // 7. LOOP WITH STATIC FUNCTION
            stopwatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < oneTestDuration; i++)
            {
                myClass.staticEmptyFunction();
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            timesList.Add(new myTime(stopwatch, (TimeType)7));
            stopwatch.Reset();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nDONE TESTING");
    }

    static void GetResults()
    {
        // SUMS
        double sum1t, sum2t, sum3t, sum4t, sum5t, sum6t, sum7t,
            sum1m, sum2m, sum3m, sum4m, sum5m, sum6m, sum7m;
        sum1t = sum2t = sum3t = sum4t = sum5t = sum6t = sum7t =
            sum1m = sum2m = sum3m = sum4m = sum5m = sum6m = sum7m = 0;

        foreach (myTime time in timesList)
        {
            switch (time.type)
            {
                case (TimeType)1: sum1t += time.ticks; sum1m += time.miliseconds; break;
                case (TimeType)2: sum2t += time.ticks; sum2m += time.miliseconds; break;
                case (TimeType)3: sum3t += time.ticks; sum3m += time.miliseconds; break;
                case (TimeType)4: sum4t += time.ticks; sum4m += time.miliseconds; break;
                case (TimeType)5: sum5t += time.ticks; sum5m += time.miliseconds; break;
                case (TimeType)6: sum6t += time.ticks; sum6m += time.miliseconds; break;
                case (TimeType)7: sum7t += time.ticks; sum7m += time.miliseconds; break;
            }
        }

        // AVERAGES
        double avg1t, avg2t, avg3t, avg4t, avg5t, avg6t, avg7t,
            avg1m, avg2m, avg3m, avg4m, avg5m, avg6m, avg7m;

        avg1t = sum1t / (double)testTimesCount;
        avg2t = sum2t / (double)testTimesCount;
        avg3t = sum3t / (double)testTimesCount;
        avg4t = sum4t / (double)testTimesCount;
        avg5t = sum5t / (double)testTimesCount;
        avg6t = sum6t / (double)testTimesCount;
        avg7t = sum7t / (double)testTimesCount;

        avg1m = sum1m / (double)testTimesCount;
        avg2m = sum2m / (double)testTimesCount;
        avg3m = sum3m / (double)testTimesCount;
        avg4m = sum4m / (double)testTimesCount;
        avg5m = sum5m / (double)testTimesCount;
        avg6m = sum6m / (double)testTimesCount;
        avg7m = sum7m / (double)testTimesCount;

        string fileName = "/result.txt";
        using (StreamWriter tr = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + fileName))
        {
            tr.WriteLine(((TimeType)1).ToString() + "\t" + avg1t + "\t" + avg1m);
            tr.WriteLine(((TimeType)2).ToString() + "\t" + avg2t + "\t" + avg2m);
            tr.WriteLine(((TimeType)3).ToString() + "\t" + avg3t + "\t" + avg3m);
            tr.WriteLine(((TimeType)4).ToString() + "\t" + avg4t + "\t" + avg4m);
            tr.WriteLine(((TimeType)5).ToString() + "\t" + avg5t + "\t" + avg5m);
            tr.WriteLine(((TimeType)6).ToString() + "\t" + avg6t + "\t" + avg6m);
            tr.WriteLine(((TimeType)7).ToString() + "\t" + avg7t + "\t" + avg7m);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunTest();

        GetResults();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When I put all the data in excel and made a chart, it looked like this (**DEBUG**):
[image: Excel chart]

**EDIT - RELEASE** version. I guess this answers my question.
[image: release version excel chart]

**The questions are**
**Q1.** What approach to use to be more efficient?
**Q2.** In what case?
**Q3.** Is there official documentation on this?
**Q4.** Did anybody else test this, maybe more intensively?
**Q5.** Is there a better way to test this (is my code at fault)?
**Q6.** Is there a better way around the problem of huge lists of instances that need to be quickly and efficiently updated, as in - every frame?
**EDIT Q7.** Why does the static method take so much longer to execute in the release version?

Comment: I can't see the image (.png) for Excel chart. Why won't that work?

Comment: Did you build it and run the test program in `Release` mode? When optimization kicks-in, there shouldn't be much different with all approach...

Comment: I didn't know that. I will do that and add another chart image

Comment: You can post that release graph and the conclusion as an answer to your own question

Comment: Your performance tests are useless to say the least... nothing about the result will be applicable in a scenario where the empty function calls are randomly mixed with other function calls. Not enough for good results, but at least you should prepare a list of instances count=OneTestDuration, so the compiler won't magically know to treat each loop iteration exactly the same. Also prepare separate test runs for each method, instead of executing them in line.

Comment: You do make a good point. But after seeing the results of the release, does it even matter if I make the test not treat every loop the same? Also, it's not about the loop here, but what's in the loop. The `for` clauses should be exactly the same. It doesn't matter how good or bad they are. This makes the running of all tests in the same function valid. What do you say to this? Also, maybe I should make a test with randomly populated list, where some instances are null, and some are not? @grek40

Comment: @HansKesting I did edit the question, but yes, I agree, I should make that an answer. Also, read my comment above. Do you agree that I should create a randomly populated list and do a test with that?

Comment: First you should ask yourself whether the performance of the null/empty cases is any significant compared to the performance of those objects that have a non-empty implementation. I couldn't figure out from your question whether you already identified this call as a possible bottleneck or you just decided to optimize it by looking at the code and feeling like you should act.

Comment: I just felt like researching it. Offcorse that there is a difference between null instance and a instanciated one. I did mention that, in my imaginary game engine, we would have to check physics, collisions, draw, input, etc. I do understand that you are saying that the difference might be negligiable, but we are pretending that it's not, because what would even be the point of this research then? I will most likely answer my own question with some more charts, when I get the time. Feel free to edit and post results of my (now your edited) test.

Comment: Can you redo your test but this time, call the `myClass.staticEmptyFunction();` once before your loop test runs start. Hint: jit compiler might decide to inline the method on the first encounter - its a bit unfair to do all the related work of a first-time call in the measured benchmark time.

Answer (score 0):

As @grek40 suggested, I did another test where I called `myClass.staticEmptyFunction();` 100 times before starting the test so that it can be cashed. I also did set `testTimesCount` to 10 000 and `oneTestDuration` to 1 000 000. Here are the results: [image]

Now, it seems much more stable. Even the little differences you can spot I blame on my google chrome, excel and deluge running in the background. The questions I asked I asked because I thought that there would be a greater difference, but I guess that the optimisation worsk much much better than I expected. I also guess that nobody did this test because they probably knew that there's C behind it, and that people did amasing work on the optimisation.